# Self signed SSL certificate in multiple devices - Is this secure enough?

Tags: android, security, ssl, mobile, tls1.2

We are trying to design a solution where we have several Smart devices and we can control every smart device from multiple phones. We will generate a Self-signed SSL Server Certificate and embed that in all the smart devices. And we will include the SSL Client certificate in all the phones. Now in order to connect a phone to the smart device the phone needs to obtain an ID (which can be obtained by scanning a QR code on the Smart device - this is just to ensure that the phone is in the vicinity of the smart device).

Smart Device:

- Embeds a Self signed Server certificate. Reason: No dependency on the
  internet connectivity
- Maintains a WiFi hotspot (Internet connectivity    is not guaranteed
  always)
- Maintains a list of connected phones (each    phone
  identified by the QR Code ID that is scanned by the phone)

Phone App:

- Implements Certificate pinning and hard codes the Client certificate
- Connects to the Wifi hotspot
- Establishes an SSL connection with the Smart device.
- In order to register for the first time it scans a QR code and for
  subsequent connections it sends the QR Code ID to provide its
  identity.

---

Can you please review the above architecture and identify any flaws with this?
Because we are installing the same server certificate in all the smart devices and the same client certificate in all the phones is there a way to hack the Smart device in some way?
If there is an SSL connection established between a smart device and a phone, can another device (which is on the same network with the same certificate) be able to hijack the packets sent between the Smart device and the first phone?
Once a secure link is established we send the QR Code ID in plain text format through the SSL socket. Do we need to encrypt this again or is the SSL link secure enough?

Comment: *we send the QR Code ID in plain text format through the SSL socket.* ... hehe but any app can read it(i mean scan the QR code and that's it)... so what is the point? Because QR code looks nifty?

Comment: The QR code is unique to each phone and it is displayed only when a phone wants to connect to the Smart device. Also for successful registration the phone has to be in the same WiFi network as the Smart device

Answer (score 1):

A much better site to ask this site of question is security.stackexchange.com. But in short:

- your are using the same certificate for authentication in all devices
- this means that all devices have the same private key
- this means that it is enough for an attacker to own and crack a single device in order to get the private key for all devices
- this means that with this private key the attacker can now be a man in the middle in the communication to all other devices. The attacker might also create its own fake devices which might successfully attack the client since the client only expects a nice behaving device using this certificate.

> Is this secure enough?

I doubt it. For a way on how to do this better I recommend to look at related questions at security.stackexchange.com and if you don't find one ask there for recommendations on a better design.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your smart devices are distinguished by some IP address.

> Implements Certificate pinning and hard codes the Client certificate

I guess you wanted to say you are hard coding server certificate in Phone App.
You should not be using SSL3. As per industry standard focus on TLS 1.1, 1.2.
Though I would like to point out, this architecture is not secure enough. Since all smart device use same certificate, If the certificate is leaked, every device is subject to be compromised by MiM attack.

> Do we need to encrypt this again or is the SSL link secure enough?

You don't need to encrypt the QR id as they are going through secure channel.